# Jumping not working(you can jump infinitly)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, game-physics

Hi im begginer of C# and Unity and im making movements for the player.
I used code from tutorial on youtube.
But this code is not working as it is supposed to.
The code worked for the guy on youtube but not for me.
Everything is working except jumping.
You can jump but you will jum infinitly mid-air.
The guy wrote one line of code to avoid this but its not working for me.
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("Move Variables")]
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float walkSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float runSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;

    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    private CharacterController controller;

    [Header("Gravity")]
    [SerializeField] private float gravity;
    [SerializeField] private float groundDistance;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundMask;
    [SerializeField] private bool isCharacterGrounded = false;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    private void Start()
    {
        GetReferences();
        InitVariables();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleIsGrounded();
        HandleJumping();
        HandleGravity();
        HandleRunning();
        HandleMovement();
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveZ = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDirection = new Vector3(moveX, 0, moveZ);
        moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized;

        controller.Move(moveDirection * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void HandleRunning()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = runSpeed;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
        }
    }

    private void HandleIsGrounded()
    {
        isCharacterGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, groundDistance);
    }

    private void HandleGravity()
    {
        if (isCharacterGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void HandleJumping()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isCharacterGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpForce * -2 * gravity);
        }
    }

    private void GetReferences()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void InitVariables()
    {
        moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
    }
}
```

So when i apply this to player the check box that says : "Is Character Grounded" is always cheked even mid-air.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What value is `groundDistance?`

Comment: ground distance is how far u need to be above the ground for the box to be unchecked i think

Comment: @Bendas627 This question cannot be answered without knowing what `groundDistance` is set to.

Comment: i just commented

Comment: and i have it set to 0.2

Comment: Your sphere is almost certainly overlappig with your character's colider and returing true becase of that. `CheckSphere` is probaly the wrong tool for this. I would use `Physics.SphereCast` and using the hit info struct, make sure the object you hit was actually the ground

Comment: i made this with my code : isCharacterGrounded = Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, groundDistance);

Comment: it gave me this error: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Ray'

Comment: i can send web adress for the tutorial if you need

Comment: can anyone help? i will be glad for any usefull information and please i am really begginer of unity so i need like further explenation if possible, if not its not that necessary

Answer (score 0):

I have it solved. Only one thing that I needed to do was to add `,groundMask`
to the end of  `isCharacterGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, groundDistance);`